# Text view change when user scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

[Text view changes as user scroll the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Y6v.gif)

How can i achieve something like that as shown in gif file above link...
I have nested scroll view in activity and layout frame inside it, in which fragment is added..
That fragment contains multi recycler views and their title layout...I was unable to achieve this..please help

Comment: show what you have got so far. this "feature" is called "list section header". to be more exact "`RecyclerView` header" and best match would be "sticky `RecyclerView` header". plenty of solutions can be found in internet, even [some official tutorials](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-headers) for Kotlin

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, simply give each container/section a name variable, then simply match up the scroll location with the container on screen and grab the text variable that you stored previously. Using your favourite search engine search for things like "Android get scroll location" and "Android get component location y value" etc and you'll have your answer in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect called "Sticky Header" and you can achieve it without using third party libs.
[Here is tutorial](https://medium.com/@saber.solooki/sticky-header-for-recyclerview-c0eb551c3f68) and [direct link to code](https://gist.github.com/saber-solooki/edeb57be63d2a60ef551676067c66c71)

Comment: Yuriy thnx.. finally solved my problem